# Votes should be provided slowly over time, rather than all at once

Tags: feature-request, voting, voting-limits

Rather than reseting all the voting limits at one arbitrary time each day, increment each user's available votes every 48 minutes with a maximum of 30.  If you haven't been here for a day you have 30 votes you can use immediately, but then rather than waiting another 19 hours, you'll get another one in less than an hour.

It should increase participation, and, more importantly, provide more even voting across a range of questions and answers rather than a huge voting spree in the morning tapering off during the day as people run out of votes.

Comment: Would having to work interfere?

Comment: @Remou Sleeping does as well.  But that's an end-user problem.

Comment: As long as the counter stays at 30, and doesn't automatically reset to 0 when the clock strikes 12, then I guess this is an improvement.

Comment: I imagine this could complicate the calculations for the Suffrage badge, depending on the mechanics. Would it be a set 48-minute interval (12:00, 12:48, ...), or would it be 48 minutes after the user last used a vote (or regained a vote)?

Comment: Yes please, **and do this for close votes as well**.

Comment: +1, but why 48 minutes?  What's special about 48?

Comment: @John, 24 hours / 30 = 48 minuets.

Comment: @Brian: How musical!