# Amortize voting limits over a rolling week

Tags: feature-request, voting, voting-limits

We can cast a maximum of 40 votes (up/down) per day¹.

For people who vote a lot — which [is](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) [encouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) — this maximum can be reached pretty quickly. I know why there's a maximum — we wouldn't want a users to indiscriminately vote on everything — but 40 votes is not a lot, and the fact that it's a *daily* limit makes it much lower due to the days we don't hit the limit.

There's a Stack Exchange site that I visit pretty regularly, for the most part once per day, and where I very often run out of votes. On average over a week, I vote about 200 times — but per day, the number of votes I'd like to cast varies from about 20 to about 60, because of the variance of quality (plus week-ends have fewer posts). And that's only if I manage to go through questions every day: if I miss a UTC day then I lose that day's votes.

Please make the vote limit a rolling limit on a longer time basis. 40 votes per day *amortized over a 7-day period* would be good.

Related: [Votes should be provided slowly over time, rather than all at once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79032/votes-should-be-provided-slowly-over-time-rather-than-all-at-once) — but doing it that way would hurt me a lot, because I usually visit the site once a day and browse that day's posts in one go.

¹  <sub>With additional restrictions related to the number of votes on questions, and we get votes back from deleted posts, but neither matter here.</sub>

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being obtuse, but would that mean that in certain circumstances someone could vote 280 times in a single 24-hour period?

Comment: @Nathaniel Yes (and then you'd be unable to vote for a week).

Comment: 'Vote early, vote often'... Am not sure this is better than encouraging marginal users to vote.

Comment: Maybe in the top page header should exist a counter, to continously help the voter to know, where he is.

Comment: @peterh [Yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239601/reliable-count-of-votes-that-ive-cast-today), like there [used to be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207464#207464)